# Random string generator: Unicode out of range?

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to make a random string generator in C#, given a length of the string. My first attempt was this:

```
public static string RandomString(int characters)
{
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < characters; i++)
    {
        s += Convert.ToChar((97 + r.Next(26)));
    }
    return s;
}
```

But the frequencies of the letters before *k* were very low, so I tried to change it by writing my own randomizer:

```
public static string RandomString(int characters)
{
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < characters; i++)
    {
        int randomLetter = 0;

        for (int bit = 0; i < 5; bit++)
        {
            if (r.Next(2) == 0)
                continue;
            randomLetter += 1 << bit;

            if (randomLetter + (1 << (bit + 1)) > 26)
                break;
        }
        s += Convert.ToChar(97 + randomLetter);
    }
    return s;
}
```

But sometimes randomLetter will be greater than 26, sometimes way too great. I can't find the cause of this problem, can you?

Comment: There is no difference between the two code snippets

Comment: `for (int bit = 0; i < 5; bit++)` < you are not updating `i` variable here which is used in a loop end condition, doubt that was intended.

Comment: Oh of course. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just one note if you need I truly random number don't use Random class.

Comment: *"writing my own randomizer"* > That is most likely not a good idea, you should stick to the "established" code provided by the framework, which is thoroughly tested and used by many other people...

Comment: What do you mean low frequency? The generated randomizer is actually a lot worse than `Random` . What was wrong with the *original* random sequence, how many values did you generate, what did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: More random than Random? No.

Comment: *"the frequencies of the letters before k were very low"* : I'm deeply suspicious of this statement.

Comment: This is pretty much a poster child for the statement "Don't write your own PRNG if you don't know what you're doing".

Comment: I suggest that you study the result of this query before you make sweeping statements about the randomness of random: `Enumerable.Range(0,2000).SelectMany(_=>RandomString(2000)).GroupBy(c=>c).Select(g=>new{g.Key,Count=g.Count()})`. Using this method, we select 2000 strings that are 2000 long and count how many occurrences we have of each character. I don't see anything to suggest any skew at all... In fact, my first run had top 5 entries below *k*. In short, the premise of this question is fundamentally broken and (while not particularly efficient) your first attempt at this was fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a simple random string, this approach should be much simpler:

```
private static Random random = new Random();

public static string GetRandomString(int length)
{
    var chars = new char[length];
    var possibleLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";        

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        chars[i] = possibleLetters[random.Next(0, possibleLetters.Length - 1)];
    }

    return new string(chars);
}
```

I just made a console test with your code against mine:

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   string s = RandomString(10000);
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
sw.Restart();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    string s = GetRandomString(10000);
}

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
Console.Read();
```

RESULTS:

```
RandomString => 18830,7537
GetRandomString => 321.098
```

As you can see, your implementation is not only worse to read, but also performs much slower.

To justify curiosity, I recreated my method with a StringBuilder instead:

```
private static string GetRandomStringSB(int length)
{
   var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(length);

   var possibleLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
       stringBuilder.Append(possibleLetters[r.Next(0, possibleLetters.Length - 1)]);
   }

   return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Not surprisingly, the results didn't defer much:

```
RandomString (OP) => 13175
GetRandomString (char[]) => 213
GetRandomStringSB (StringBuilder) => 244
```

Comment: This would make it very inefficient and wouldn't take away the low frequency in the lower letter range.

Comment: @AlexJanse not sure how much more inefficient could it really be, did you test it out?

Comment: Similarly, but probably more readable: `var possibleLetters = "abcdefghi...";`. You can apply exactly the same indexer to a `string` that you can to a `char[]`.

Comment: @AlexJanse I just made a console test. Your implementation is MUCH slower. ( 1000 iterations, 1000 characters => 507ms your implementation, 29ms mine),

Comment: What are you doing that the speed of generation of a random string actually affects the overall speed? This sounds like you are trying to optimise something that doesn't need it at the expense of readability. I'm also surprised that 5 loops per character generating a new random integer each time isn't significantly slower.

Comment: Typo: instead of `chars.ToString();` should be `new string(chars);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko my bad, fixed!

Comment: Nice idea with the `char[]` array (when automatic reaction is `StringBuilder`); `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` constant (it's easy to -*skip* the letter or add it *twice* while printing) is a bit disappointing; recreating `Random` - `var random = new Random();` is an *evil* which can lead to badly skewed distributions. Please, push `var random = new Random();` *out* of method's body and have my `+1`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I put the new Random inline just to show the OP since he didn't declare it anywhere, but of course in my test the Random was declared as a private static field. Thanks for the review!

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I just made one more update since you left me curious :)

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto: `StringBuilder` is a proper way (since the class has been specially designed for building strings); however, it inevitably adds (small) overhead. `char[]` adds nothing and that's why is faster.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I'd say any of my implementations or even yours is still much better than what the OP uses anyway (both in terms of performance and readability)

Answer (score 2):

Why all these *bitwise* arithmetics? First, let's state the problem:

> I want to generate *random* string of `characters` length; the string should consist of `a`..`z`
>   which should have uniform distribution

And implementation will be easy:

```
// Simplest, but not thread safe
private static Random s_Random = new Random();

// Not thread safe
public static string RandomString(int characters) {
  if (characters < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("characters");

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(characters);

  // I personally, prefer Linq + Concat, but let's preserve the loop
  for (int i = 0; i < characters; ++i) {
    char c = (char)(s_Random.Next('z' - 'a' + 1) + 'a'); // +1 - 'z' should be included

    sb.Append(c);
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

*Linq* version is *shorter*, but, probably, less *readable*:

```
// Not thread safe
public static string RandomString(int characters) {
  if (characters < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("characters");

  return string.Concat(Enumerable
    .Range(0, characters)
    .Select(i => (char)(s_Random.Next('z' - 'a' + 1) + 'a')));
}
```

Test:

```
Console.Write(RandomString(10));
```

Outcome (may vary):

```
dcdwwvzhnz
```

Finally, let's have a look at the actual *distribution* "...But the **frequencies** of the letters **before** `k` were **very low**.."

```
  int count = 1000; // we examine "count" random string
  int length = 10;  // each of "length" length 

  var distribution = String
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, count).Select(i => RandomString(length)))
    .GroupBy(c => c, (k, s) => new {
      key = k,
      freq = (double)s.Count() / length / count
    })
    .OrderBy(item => item.freq)
    .Select(item => $"{item.key}: {item.freq:F4}")
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, distribution));
```

Outcome (may vary): *no evidence* of such a *skew*

```
p: 0.0351
a: 0.0359
r: 0.0360
y: 0.0362
l: 0.0363
z: 0.0364
n: 0.0369
u: 0.0370
h: 0.0371
e: 0.0373
c: 0.0375
v: 0.0376
x: 0.0376
o: 0.0380
q: 0.0380
m: 0.0388
k: 0.0389
d: 0.0391
s: 0.0391
g: 0.0396
w: 0.0401
b: 0.0406
t: 0.0406
f: 0.0422
i: 0.0434
j: 0.0447
```

Comment: I don't think the OP did any test to be sure of what he claims. Nice answer though!

Comment: You could also write `r.Next('a','z'+1)`, using the [Next(Int32,Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) overload

Answer (score 0):

With these methods you can specify valid characters, or accept all of them.

```
    public static string RandomString(int len)
    {
        var array = Enumerable.Range(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue - char.MinValue + 1).Select(x => (char)x).ToArray();
        return RandomString(len, array);
    }

    private static string RandomString(int len, char[] array)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (sb.Length < len)
            sb.Append(array[r.Next(array.Length-1)]);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple Function that you can generate Random string

```
 public static string RandomString(int length)
        {
            string functionReturnValue = null;
            Random MyRandom = new Random();
            functionReturnValue = null;
            for (int MyLoop = 1; MyLoop <= length; MyLoop++)
            {
                if (MyLoop % 2 == 1)
                {
                    functionReturnValue = functionReturnValue + Convert.ToChar(MyRandom.Next(97, 123));
                }
                if (MyLoop % 2 == 0)
                {
                    functionReturnValue = functionReturnValue + MyRandom.Next(1, 10);
                }
            }

            return functionReturnValue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want random.

```
private static System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator random = System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
public static string Random(int characters)
        {
            var data = new byte[characters];
            random.GetBytes(data);
            return data.Select(b=>Convert.ToChar((int)(96 + (Math.Floor((b/(double)byte.MaxValue)*27)) - 1))).Aggregate(new System.Text.StringBuilder(),(a,c) => a.Append(c)).ToString();
        }
```

Note this is not fast but random

Answer (score -3):

Thanks to @Evk I figured it out. My final approach:

```
public static string RandomString(int characters)
    {
        string s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < characters; i++)
        {
            int ascii = 0;

            for (int bit = 0; bit < 5; bit++)
            {
                if (r.Next(2) == 0)
                    continue;
                ascii += 1 << bit;

                if (ascii + (1 << (bit + 1)) > 25)
                    break;
            }
            s += Convert.ToChar(97 + ascii);
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: Shifting and adding on top of a very short sequence does *not* produce a good random sequence. What was wrong with the built-in randomizer? What do you mean "low frequency' ?

Comment: If you simply try to calculate the frequency you'll see that this is worse. The middle letters k-p appear twice as often as the other letters